# Find if value exists in multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I have 4 list and each element on the list are unique across the 4 list. How do I find if the value exist in one of the list and return which list it exist?

Example list:

```
value = 'a'
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['d','e','f']
d = ['g','h','i']
c = ['j','k','l']
```

My expected output is the name of the list where the value is found: 
For the example above my expected output would be:

a

Comment: `[i for i in [a,b,c,d] if value in i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your updated question, let's assume the `a, b, c, d` variables are in the global scope

```
value = 'a'
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['d','e','f']
d = ['g','h','i']
c = ['j','k','l']

w = next(n for n,v in filter(lambda t: isinstance(t[1],list), globals().items()) if value in v)
print(w)
```

produces

```
a
```

i.e. the name of the first list in the global namespace that contains `value`

If the variables are in a local scope, e.g. within a function, you can use `locals()` instead

```
def f():
    a = ['a','b','c']
    b = ['d','e','f']
    d = ['g','h','i']
    c = ['j','k','l']
    w = next(n for n,v in filter(lambda t: isinstance(t[1],list), locals().items()) if value in v)
    print(w)

f()
```

produces

```
a
```

Note: you might want to adopt a naming convention to target a specific group of variables, e.g. `targ_` as a prefix

```
targ_a = ['a','b','c']
targ_b = ['d','e','f']
targ_d = ['g','h','i']
targ_c = ['j','k','l']
w = next(n for n,v in filter(lambda t: isinstance(t[1],list) and t[0].startswith('targ_'), globals().items()) if value in v)
print(w)
```

produces

```
targ_a
```

To explain things a bit more in detail, let's have a look at what the `globals()` call returns. For example using the python shell

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> value = 'a'
>>> targ_a = ['a','b','c']
>>> targ_b = ['d','e','f']
>>> targ_d = ['g','h','i']
>>> targ_c = ['j','k','l']
>>> globals()
{'targ_d': ['g', 'h', 'i'], 'targ_c': ['j', 'k', 'l'],
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 '__doc__': None, '__package__': None,
 '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>,
 'targ_a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '__name__': '__main__',
 'targ_b': ['d', 'e', 'f'], '__spec__': None, 'value': 'a'}
```

as you can see, `globals()` returns a dictionary. Its keys are the names of the variables defined in the global namespace. Its values are the value held by each such variable.

Therefore

```
>>> next(n for n,v in filter(lambda t: isinstance(t[1],list) and t[0].startswith('targ_'), globals().items()) if value in v)
'targ_a'
```

iterates once on the generator produced by the expression, which yields each name in the global namespace that corresponds to a list whose name starts with `targ_` and that contains an element equal to `value`. It does so by iterating on the dictionary returned by the call to `globals`

Comment: Thank you for different solutions you provided. How come you did not call any of the list names? @Pynchia

Comment: Thank you, i now understand @Pynchia

Comment: This answer gives the OP exactly what they want, and I can't fault it for that. But warning to future readers: using `globals()` or `locals()` is almost always a bad idea. If you want to get a string containing a variable name, that's a strong indication that there's a design problem with your code and you should consider refactoring so you no longer need to do that.

Answer (score 10):

you can use `list comprehension`:

```
>>> value ="a"
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = ['d','e','f']
>>> d = ['g','h','i']
>>> c = ['j','k','l']
>>> [x for x in a,b,c,d if value in x]
[['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

To get variable name:

```
>>> for x in a,b,c,d:
...     if value in x:
...         for key,val in locals().items():
...             if x == val:
...                 print key
...                 break
... 
a
```

> > locals() contains local scope variable as dictionary, variable name being key and its value being value
> >
> > globals  contains global scope variable as dictionary, variable name being key and its value being value

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a list comprehension, you can always use a convoluted and verbose lambda expression!

`list(filter(lambda x: value in x, [a,b,c,d]))`

EDIT: Question was updated to ask for var name, not var value

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is almost always a bad idea. Suppose you do get a string containing the name of the list you want. What do you do with it then? There's no nice way to get a variable if all you have is a string containing its name. You can do it with `globals()` or `locals()`, but those inevitably make your code messy and confusing.

The correct way to do this is to use a list or a dictionary to collect all of the lists you want to search through. Iterating through a single object is much better practice than iterating through every name in the global or local scope.

```
value = "a"
named_lists = {
    "a": ['a','b','c'],
    "b": ['d','e','f'],
    "d": ['g','h','i'],
    "c": ['j','k','l']
}

names = [name for name, seq in named_lists.items() if value in seq]
print(names)
if names: #there may be multiple lists that contain `value`, so let's just look at the first one, if it exists
    first_name = names[0] 
    print(named_lists[first_name])
```

Result:

```
['a']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```