# Find in which of multiple sets a value belongs to

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have several sets of values, and need to check in which of some of them a given value is located, and return the name of that set.

```
value = 'a'
set_1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
set_2 = {'d', 'e', 'f'}
set_3 = {'g', 'h', 'i'}
set_4 = {'a', 'e', 'i'}
```

I'd like to check if value exists in sets 1-3, without including set_4 in the method, and return the set name. So something like:

```
find_set(value in set_1, set_2, set_3)
```

should return

```
set_1
```

Maybe some neat lambda function? I tried

```
w = next(n for n,v in filter(lambda t: isinstance(t[1],set), globals().items()) if value in v)
```

from [Find if value exists in multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783084/find-if-value-exists-in-multiple-lists) but that approach checks ALL local/global sets. That won't work here, because the value can exist in several of them. I need to be able to specify in which sets to look.

Comment: Why do you need the name?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I want to change the name of the value into that of the set name. This is a function to identify different forms of writing of the same thing. E.g. I'd like to check if TRASTUTSUMAB in trastutsumab = {Trastutsumab, trastutsumab, TRASTUTSUMAB, ....} and change the value to trastutsumab. (I'm working on hospital statistics of medicines that have been prescribed in the past 20 years, and the form of writing has changed for many of the drugs over the years)

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* use an ugly hackish lambda which digs in `globals` so you can get a name; that will confuse anyone reading your code including yourself after a few weeks :-).

You want to be able to get a name for sets you have defined, well, this is why we have dictionaries. Make a dictionary out of your sets and then you can create handy/readable set/list comprehensions to get what you want in a compact readable fashion:

```
>>> d = {'set_1': set_1, 'set_2': set_2, 'set_3': set_3, 'set_4': set_4}
```

To catch all sets in which `'a'` is located:

```
>>> {name for name, items in d.items() if 'a' in items}
{'set_1', 'set_4'}
```

To exclude some name add another the required clause to the `if` for filtering:

```
>>> {name for name, items in d.items() if 'a' in items and name != 'set_4'}
{'set_1'}
```

You can of course factor this into a function and be happy you'll be able to understand it if you bump into it in the future:

```
def find_sets(val, *excludes, d=d):
    return {n for n, i in d.items() if val in i and n not in excludes}
```

This behaves in a similar way as the previous. `d=d` is probably not the way you want to do it, you'll probably be better of using some `**d` syntax for this.

---

If you just want to get the first value, return the `next(comprehension)` from your function like this:

```
def find_sets(val, *excludes, d=d):
    return next((n for n, i in d.items() if val in i and n not in excludes), '')
```

The `''` just indicates a default value to be returned if no elements are actually found, that is, when called with a value that isn't present, an empty string will be returned (subject to change according to your preferences):

```
>>> find_sets('1')
''
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This should work and yes, it is far less confusing than what I tried.

Comment: Oh, one final thing. This returns a set (of set names). In my case there'll always just one correct set name, so rather than returning {'name'}, I'd like the function to return just 'name'. I guess I could just 'pop' the single value from the set, but is there an easy modification to the above code that accomplishes the same?

Comment: @AnttiEllonen you could either use a list comprehension and return `[n for n, i in d.items() if val in i and n not in excludes][0]` i.e the first item, or, use `next` and get the first value of the supplied iterator as demonstrate in my updated answer.