# Find if value exists in multiple list and get names of it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found similar question, but I'm not able to convert answer to match my needs.
([Find if value exists in multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783084/find-if-value-exists-in-multiple-lists))

So, basicly, I have multiple lists, and I want to list all of them, which contain current user username.

```
import getpass


value = getpass.getuser()
rep_WOHTEL = ['user1','user2','user3']
rep_REPDAY = ['user4','user1','user3']
rep_ZARKGL = ['user3','user1','user2']
rep_WOHOPL = ['user3','user2','user5']


#No idea how code below works
w = next(n for n,v in filter(lambda t: isinstance(t[1],list) and t[0].startswith('rep_'), globals().items()) if value in v)
print(w)
```

If current user is user1, I want it to print `rep_WOHTEL`, `rep_REPDAY` and `rep_ZARKGL`. Code above print only ony of them.

How should I change this part of script, to print all I want?

Comment: You managed to make something that sounded simple from reading the title completely confusing with your description. Why do you want to print three lists if the user is `'user1'`, what does that have to do with the question and who wrote that abomination of a generator expression at the end?

Comment: Don't do this; make a dictionary like `{'rep_WOHTEL': ['user1','user2','user3'], 'rep_REPDAY':['user4','user1','user3']}`

Comment: All of the solutions in that linked question are using questionable techniques to achieve a questionable goal. Please don't assume that any of them are the "right" way to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if value is in all global lists, and if true, print which list(s) contains the required value.

**Code:**

```
rep_WOHTEL = ['user1','user2','user3']
rep_REPDAY = ['user4','user1','user3']
rep_ZARKGL = ['user3','user1','user2']
rep_WOHOPL = ['user3','user2','user5']

value = 'user1'
x = globals().items()
for n,v in filter(lambda t: isinstance(t[1],list) and t[0].startswith('rep_'), x):
    if value in v:
        print(n)
```

**Output:**

```
rep_REPDAY
rep_ZARKGL
rep_WOHTEL
```

**More info about the used functions:**

- [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)
- [dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)
- [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)
- [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)
- [startswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Comment: Thank you. And sorry for the way i asked question if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Like I commented in the linked question, iterating through all of `globals()` or `locals()` is a bad idea. Store your lists together in a single dictionary or list, and iterate through that instead.

```
value = "user1"
named_lists = {
    "WOHTEL": ['user1','user2','user3'],
    "REPDAY": ['user4','user1','user3'],
    "ZARKGL": ['user3','user1','user2'],
    "WOHOPL": ['user3','user2','user5']
}

names = [name for name, seq in named_lists.items() if value in seq]
print(names)
```

Result:

```
['REPDAY', 'ZARKGL', 'WOHTEL']
```

Comment: As I commented, this is definitely the right way for nearly all use cases